# How to decrease the size of the svg used in : animated skills diagram with Raphael

Tags: animation, svg, resize, raphael

I implemented the following plugin into my website http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/22/animated-skills-diagram/comment-page-3/#comments

Unfortunately the set width of the svg used is 600px x 600px. I tried to overwrite the size to a smaller one of 350 px, but it did not work. is simply cuts off a part of the svg. Could anyone give me advise on how to make the animation smaller?

Thanks in advance,
Ev Chen

Answer (score 0):

You can use a viewbox to scale the svg. Set the svg container to the size you want that normally causes cropping, and then set the viewbox to be 600px x 600px, allowing resizing

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setViewBox

```
paper.setViewBox(0, 0, 600, 600, true)
```

This will fit the specified region (600 x 600) into the container.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply.I had a good look through the files provided with the plugin but unfortunately I cannot figure out, where I have to place the paper.setViewBox .I am really new to this but would love to use this plugin, since it fits into my project really well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dj96k/ - See this example, it demonstrates the basic use of setViewBox. The circle drawn on the paper is 64px x 64px, which is larger than the paper size of 32px x 32px. Using setViewBox we can change the area being displayed.

In the example you refer to, you would want to do something like:

`var r = Raphael('diagram', 350, 350),
    rad = 73;

r.setViewBox(0, 0, 600, 600);`